# cant use flipbook in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

i am trying to use flipbook in my vue js project. i saw their documentation. has anybody used it before.? if you do then please show me an example. here is my code below of what i had tired so far.
this is my test.vue file

```
<template>
  <flipbook :pages="pages" v-slot="flipbook">
     <button @click="flipbook.flipLeft">Previous Page</button>
     <button @click="flipbook.flipRight">Next Page</button>
  </flipbook>
</template>
```

the scirp file

```
   import Flipbook from 'flipbook-vue'
   import flipbook from "@/components/flipbook";

   export default {
       name: "RwvSettings",
       pages: [
           null,
           'images/1.jpg',
           'images/2.jpg',
           'images/3.jpg',
           'images/4.jpg'
           ],
      components: { flipbook },
  };
```

and this is the component

```
 <template>
    <div slot v-bind="{
      page
        }" />
   </div>
 </template>

 <script>
    export default {
        name: "flipbook",
        props: {
        pages: {
           type: Array,
           required: true
        }
    }

 }
```

it shows nothing. please someone help me resolve this issue

Comment: I am facing the same problem with flipbook-vue.

Comment: hello priya. Did you solve your problem.? i had solved my problem back then. i have provided an answer.  you can check .

Answer (score 1):

i had found the problem why any image didn't appear .
firstly,  it doesn't appear if the height and width of flipbook class is not defiend.

add a class

```
 <flipbook class="flipbook" :pages="pages" v-slot="flipbook">
    <button @click="flipbook.flipLeft">Previous Page</button>
    <button @click="flipbook.flipRight">Next Page</button>
 </flipbook>
```

then in style

```
.flipbook {
   width: 90vw;
   height: 90vh;
}
```

also slidely change the script  codes as below

```
export default {
   name: 'App',
   data(){
     return {
        pages: [
            null,
           'images/2.jpg',
           'images/3.jpg'
            ],
         }
   },

    components: {
        flipbook 
    }
 }
```

now the images will appear in a flipbook

Comment: I have solved my problem but know i want to make interactive flipbook page. We can show text and select that. some media will be shown on page like (image,audio, video). Do some operation like audio playing, video playing, recording etc. You know how to do this type of functionality with flipbook-vue.

Comment: you will find some methods in vue-flipbook's documentation. you have to code inside those functions